# Error: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am a beginner in R and I need to export R markdown file into pdf. I downloaded MikTex, TexStudio and uploaded the package tinytex. I tried to plug the code \begin{document} but it doesn't seem to be working, so I am not sure if I am plugging it in the right space.

````
    output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 7
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  html_document: default
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
header-includes: |
  ```{=latex}
  \usepackage{fvextra}
  \begin{document}
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{
    showspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    breaklines,
    commandchars=\\\{\}
always_allow_html: yes
````

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of syntax errors:

- `output:` should not be indented. This is a parent key for `pdf_document:` etc.
- `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{` is missing the closing `}`
- you don't actually need to escape to raw latex in the `header-includes:`
- Don't use `\begin{document}` in the preamble.
- "I downloaded [...] TexStudio" -> TeXstudio is not really great for editing rmd files. I suggest to have a look at Rstudio instead.

---

```
---
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    fig_height: 6
    fig_width: 7
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    keep_tex: true
  html_document: default
  word_document:
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '3'
header-includes: |
  \usepackage{fvextra}
  \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{Highlighting}{Verbatim}{
    showspaces = false,
    showtabs = false,
    breaklines,
    commandchars=\\\{\}
  }
always_allow_html: yes
---


test
```